# C getopt -<integer>

Tags: c, getopt

How do I get the option *-10* from command line arguments- "*tail -10*". getopt function finds *'1'* character. But how do I access the string *"10"*?

If this can be done by getopt_long, an example would help. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect getopt doesn't support single-dash multi-character options, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you intend for `-1` to be an option with `0` as its argument, the answer is you don't. `getopt` is only made for processing options that fit the standard POSIX utilities' option syntax. It may be possible to use GNU `getopt_long` for this purpose, or you could just write your own `argv` parser (it's easy).

Edit: Actually I think I misread what you want. If you want `-` followed by any number to be interpreted as an option with that numeric value, I don't think there's any version of `getopt` that will work. There's no way you can special-case every single number as an option, and if you simply tell `getopt` that all of the digits are option characters that take arguments, `-123` will be interpreted as a `-1` option with an argument of `23` (which is fine, you can interpret it from there), but a lone `-1` will cause the next `argv` element to get `eaten` as an argument to `-1`, which is difficult or impossible to recover from.

Comment: I don't think getopt_long will do it, it requires `--` in front of the argument

Comment: If I remember correctly, `getopt_long` includes a 'long-only' option (or perhaps a separate function `getopt_longonly`?) which accepts either a single `-` or a double `--`.

Comment: Thanks. I am tempted to not use the getopt function.
"-123" through getopt is option: -1 and optarg: NULL. We loose the string "23", its not in optarg. Can I access it any other way?

Comment: Decided not to use getopt. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What is going on here is that c the language comes with *absolutely* no standard about the proper way to handle command line options.

Moreover, the unix world had no such standard for quite some time ( believe there is a whole section about it in the [Unix Haters Handbook (PDF link)](http://simson.net/ref/ugh.pdf)).

So, people wrote *ad hoc* handling mechanisms. These eventually evolved toward a common(ish) standard and `getopt` was born (at Bell labs). Later we got the GNU `getopt` and `getopt_long`. These are not required, however, and some programs still manage things their own way.

But before things settled down (and occasionally after), people added new features to the "usual" way of handling options *whenever* they seemed like a good idea. Now, it's a pretty good bet that `tail` will want to have the *number* of lines adjusted more often than any other feature, so making it *easy* and *few keystrokes* to adjust must have seemed like a good idea at the time...

Answer (score 0):

I never did like getopt that much, so I did the usual thing and reinvented the wheel. I call my solution argopt. You can get the source and manual page at https://github.com/colding/argopt. It is, I think, much easier to use than getopt.

Comment: -1: while your solution might be good, this is not the place to push it (especially if you are reinventing the wheel). Also, you seem to be the only one developing/using it.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, I would recommend changing the command argument syntax to avoid numeric arguments, either by passing the number as an option argument (e.g. `-n -5`) or allowing it only after the `--` option delimiter.

For cases where changing the argument syntax is not possible, the [BUGS section of the BSD getopt(3) man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getopt&sektion=3#BUGS) documents a way to do this.  I've adjusted their solution to avoid `optreset`, which is [not specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) and [not supported by glibc](https://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2004/10/msg00086.html):

```
int ch;
long num;
char *numarg;

while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "0123456789")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        numarg = argv[optind - 1];
        if (numarg[0] == '-' && numarg[1] == ch && numarg[2] == '\0') {
            num = '0' - ch;
        } else if ((numarg = argv[optind]) != NULL && numarg[1] == ch) {
            char *ep;
            int numoptind = optind;

            num = strtol(numarg, &ep, 10);
            if (*ep != '\0') {
                fprintf(stderr, "illegal number -- %s\n", numarg);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            /* Advance getopt internal state to next argument. */
            while (optind == numoptind) {
                ch = getopt(argc, argv, "0123456789");
                assert(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9');
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "number after other options -- %s\n", numarg);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        break;

    default:
        /* Unrecognized option character.  Error printed by getopt. */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

You can replace `getopt` with `getopt_long` and add additional short or long options as necessary.